# Ordering topics by most replies in X days using MYSQL statement

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following MySQL statement to grab the topics (BBpress custom post type) that have the most replies (custom post type like comments) in the last X days.

However I've found that I get more topics returned when I change $duration to '-7 days' than  when I use '-30 days', which makes no sense.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
// Set how far back I want to look
$period = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));

// Grab all replies in the last 30 days and group them by the topic they are attached to
$query = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT post_parent, count( post_parent ) AS c, SUBSTRING( post_date, 1, 10 ) AS d
    FROM        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE       (post_date >= %s) AND (post_type = 'reply')
    GROUP BY post_parent
    ORDER BY c DESC , d DESC
    ", $period);

// Put the return topic ID's into an array for use with WP_Query
$col_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);
$postids = implode($col_ids,', ');

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $col_ids,
    'post_type' => 'topic',
    'posts_per_page' => 7
);
```

Comment: Grouping by `post_parent` is going to truncate your results. Only one result of the "group" will show up. Thus, by chance, you may have more in 7 days than in 30, depending on how the grouping works.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - That's intentional. The replies are being grouped by the ID of their parent topic in order to return the topic ID's. There should still be more groups returned by 30 days than 7 days. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Run the query without the grouping and parse (count) the results in PHP. Do you still see the same weird counts?